# Cannot access form data in GET request

Tags: kotlin, ktor

I've been trying to make a GET request to an endpoint defined in a ktor route, but the parameters seem to be missing no matter how I try to get them. According to the documentation, I should just be able to call `call.receive<Parameters>()` and that should yield a map containing the data, but it's always empty.

So Far, I've tried installing my own ContentNegotiator (the `convertForReceive` method is never called), accessing the queryParams (always empty as well), and using the `call.receiveParameters()` method, which is always always empty

My CURL request looks like

```sh
curl -X GET \
  http://localhost:7802/api/v2/plans \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  --data-urlencode "id[starts_with]=asdf"
```

and my endpoint looks like

```
fun Routing.plans() {
  route("plans") {
    get("") {
      val params = call.receive<Parameters>()
      println(params)
      call.respond(HttpStatusCode.NoContent)
    }
  }
}
```

I expect the parameters to contain *something*, but they are always empty.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you won't be able to use have a body with a `GET` request. With that HTTP verb, most servers do not recognize a body. If you want to send a body, I'd recommend trying to change your `GET` request to a `POST`.

I think that should get you where you need to go.

Comment: Welcome here :) Do you think. guess or *know* it ?

Comment: Thanks! I know that I've not been able to use body parameters in swagger api auto-generated code from the ktor project in a GET request, so I think that this sounds like the same issue as what the OP is running into. So I hope that this helps him :).